# Interacting with content behind a React Native <Modal />?

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-modal

I want to show a [Modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) in a React Native app but still be able to interact with content behind the modal with press and pan events. Is this possible?

It seems to block all events with content behind it which is problematic for the type of app I'm building. Any hacks around this would be welcome too.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking sounds just like an absolute component with a high zIndex value

```
     const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

     ...
     {modalVisible && <Card style={styles.modal}>
        <Text>I'm a pseudo modal</Text>
        <Pressable
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
          onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </Card>}
      ...


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
  modal: {
    backgroundColor: 'tomato',
    padding: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    top: '50%',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 9999
  }
  ...
});
```

https://snack.expo.io/@diedu89/pseudomodal

You probably need to work out a custom component, I don't see any option in the Modal component to get that behavior

Comment: Makes sense. The problem with that for me was I built heavily on react-native-modal which uses the standard modal internally. I had to [patch the library to allow passing a custom modal component](https://github.com/mhluska/react-native-modal/commit/e3a552f556b88d2bce55f3b17a721cbed0479df2).

Comment: @Maros have you tried the `coverScreen` prop?

Comment: Hmm I have not. Maybe that's what was causing my issue. I'll try it in the morning and let you know how it went.

Comment: @Maros did the `coverScreen` prop make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `react-native-modal`, Set the `hasBackdrop`, `coverScreen` prop to false and `backdropOpacity` to 0 to get interactive background.

Comment: I tried this but still not able to intract

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and can confirm that adding `coverScreen={false}` and `hasBackdrop={false}` is what worked for me

```js
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

<Modal
  isVisible={showModal}
  animationType="slide"
  animationInTiming={1000}
  animationOutTiming={1500}
  animationIn="slideInUp"
  animationOut="slideOutDown"
  style={styles.modalStyles}
  deviceHeight={height}
  deviceWidth={width}
  hasBackdrop={false}
  coverScreen={false}
>
```

after adding those config options, I'm able to interact with the rest of my page while the modal is still open