# Is there a way to be able to interact with the background components when Modal is visible?

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

as the title states, I am attempting to implement a modal in such way that it only takes up some part of the screen so as to allow the user to be able to interact with some of the background components. For reference I am using the `react-native-modal` library. The current screen looks like this:

[image]

I would like to be able to interact with the icons in the header (both are already wrapped in Touchable components so already clickable). However when the Modal is visible I am unable to interact with those.

My implementation is as such:

```js
<Modal
  isVisible={showModal}
  style={styles.modalContainer}
  customBackdrop={<CustomBackdrop />}
  onBackdropPress={() => setShowModal(false)}
  animationIn="fadeInDown"
  animationOut="fadeOutUp"
>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>A</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>B</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>C</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>D</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[
        styles.itemContainer,
        { borderBottomLeftRadius: 16, borderBottomRightRadius: 16 },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.label}>E</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

And my custom background looks like this:

```js
<View
  style={{
    marginTop: hp("50%"),
    flex: 1,
  }}
>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setShowModal(false)}>
    <View
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#000", height: hp("50%"), width: wp("100%") }}
    />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
```

Comment: Check this, it might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67030316/6382890

Comment: @BaderSerhan I tried using that but zIndex always throws me for a loop. Setting `zIndex:9999;position:'absolute` doesn't really seem to work and pushes all the other components down when the modal appears.

Comment: No what you need to do is to create a normal view with absolute positioning and zIndex, not a modal. I don't think there's a way to interact with a view that's behind a modal.

Answer (score 0):

I defined two properties and it worked for me:

```
<Modal
   hasBackdrop={false}
   coverScreen={false}
```

Remembering that there are two modals, one native and one external. These properties only exist in the external, so you need to install

```
npm install react-native-modal
```

And import

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal'
```